# SQL server management connect/associate

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDtwA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4teGO.png)

Hello, I am doing a homework, the tables I added are obliged to add. It will be like a company website. But since we just started to learn SQL server management studio I don't know how to connect/associate things. For exp. which table needs to have it's own id or which id needs to be connected with. Even a little help is okey, I am so lost.

Comment: Home work questions must include some own effort, since you are supposed to practice, not us! Data modelling questions without background and the knowledge of the area you are modelling cannot be answered! I'm pretty sure that there is a desvription of your data that contains what is related with what.

Comment: There is no agression here, just stating the facts. All we can see is what you put in the question. If the post does not show own effort, nor a properly formulated, specific question, we have to point that out. If your study support materials are not adequate, then thebest course of action is to ask your teacher for clarification as opposed to ask the SO community to do your home work for you!

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is very vague and need a lot of research to understand the whole concepts. I can suggest the following topics to understand database structure

1. Primary Key and Foreign Key
2. Relations in Database
3. Normalization

To understand these things you must have clear understanding of Database entities and structures. Tables,Columns,Entries